# Can I trust online app that store my credentials?

Tags: security, credentials

I'm an happy user of the xmarks service and I use it to store and share my bookmarks and my password across my computers (home, laptop, office).

I'm also quite happy of Amazon one click buy system: I can buy stuff from any computer without to get my credit card and type in the numbers.

With the recent breakthrough in the Sony network, I'm wondering if it's a good idea...

Should I stop to use that kind of services ?

Edit:
I know it is closed, and I understand why. I just stumbled upon this [news](http://www.computerworld.com/s/article/9216459/Xmarks_bookmark_sync_passwords_safe_says_LastPass?taxonomyId=17) that is relevant to this question.

> that hackers did not obtain passwords
>   linked to Xmarks, [...]
>
> Earlier in the day, LastPass forced
>   customers to reset their master
>   passwords after detecting a "traffic
>   anomaly" that may have been a hacker
>   intrusion.

Answer (score 3):

Just my two cents:

This is a somewhat subjective question but in general, mainstream services such as Amazon have a greater level of security than your personal computer. This isn't to say they're safer 
than storing information on your HDD but they're not necessarily *less* safe either.

On the subject of Sony, they were a target for attack due to a perceived slight against
the decentralized internet group 'Anon'. What had started as a call amongst that community for what amounted to  vandalism, snowballed into a massive cyber attack. Both sides in this maintain that it was not a premeditated attempt to steal information, just some bad people taking advantage of a bad situation.

I guess in short, be just as careful with your info on the web as you would be on the street. And in my opinion stay away from xmarks. They're barely keeping afloat right now and may not be paying as close attention to security as they should be.

Comment: thanx a lot. Yes, it is a very suggestive question... But it is good to have feedback from others :)